# How to compile mod_wsgi with Apache 2.2 & Python 3.2 for Windows?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I downloaded the latest source of mod_wsgi from https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/source/checkout, but I can’t compile it in Windows with Apache 2.2 & Python 3.2. There are some undefined variables because `MOD_WSGI_WITH_DAEMONS` is undefined; `MOD_WSGI_WITH_DAEMONS` is undefined because `APR_HAS_FORK` is 0.

In “mod_wsgi.c”:

```
#if APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD && APR_HAS_THREADS && APR_HAS_FORK
#define MOD_WSGI_WITH_DAEMONS 1
#endif
...
#if defined(MOD_WSGI_WITH_DAEMONS)
...
static WSGIDaemonProcess *wsgi_daemon_process = NULL;
...
#endif
```

In “apr.h”:

```
#define APR_HAS_FORK              0
```

Is there any chance I compile mod_wsgi with Apache 2.2 & Python 3.2 for Windows? If so, how?

**Update:**

In the default branch, in “wsgi_apache.h”:

```
#if (APR_MAJOR_VERSION == 0) && \
    (APR_MINOR_VERSION == 9) && \
    (APR_PATCH_VERSION < 5)
extern apr_status_t wsgi_apr_unix_file_cleanup(void *);
extern apr_status_t wsgi_apr_os_pipe_put_ex(apr_file_t **, apr_os_file_t *,
                                            int, apr_pool_t *);
#define apr_unix_file_cleanup wsgi_apr_unix_file_cleanup
#define apr_os_pipe_put_ex wsgi_apr_os_pipe_put_ex
#endif
```

But in “apr_version.h”:

```
#define APR_MAJOR_VERSION       1
...
#define APR_MINOR_VERSION       4
...
#define APR_PATCH_VERSION       5
```

So `apr_unix_file_cleanup` will not be defined.

I am using Apache 2.2.22 and Python 3.2.3 in Windows 7 (x64).

The latest mod_wsgi-3.X can be compiled to an “.so” file, but got this error:

```
mod_wsgi.so.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am worried about this. I don't know if this is a real problem.

And also, I can't load mod_wsgi module. The Apache's error log says:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
LookupError: unknown encoding: cp0
[Sat May 05 18:35:43 2012] [crit] (OS 1813)The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.  : master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

I found this: http://bugs.python.org/review/6501/diff/2518/6050. It may cause the issue. I’m not sure.

Comment: see if this helps : http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again with the very latest source code. You may also want to use the 3.X branch instead of default branch for time being.

Comment: Still can't compile the default branch because of apr’s version. This time,`apr_unix_file_cleanup` is undefined (in “wsgi_apache.c”). 3.X branch can be compiled, but can’t find the manifest file. Will the manifest be a problem?

Comment: Try again with latest trunk for apr_unix_file_cleanup() issue. What version of Apache 2.2 are you using? That issue would have only arisen if you had a really old Apache 2.2. For manifest issue add the actual error to your question. I can't keep guessing as to the problem.

Comment: Try again with latest trunk. For encoding issue, the workaround to avoid that problem is possibly causing issues with the fix that is supposed to be in Python 3.3, else they have screwed it up even more. Confirm not an issue with latest trunk and will back port to 3.X branch. For manifest issue, what VC++ version are you using. BTW, you should really take this issue to the mod_wsgi list. SO is not supposed to be a place for debugging issues like this.

Comment: The latest works, thanks! As for the manifest issue, I’m using Visual C++ 2010. I think maybe you should add “`/MANIFEST`” in “.mk” file's `LDFLAGS` so that the linker can generate the manifest file.

Comment: If it works, what is http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=265 about? Please use the mod_wsgi mailing list to try and debug problems. Filing a ticket in the mod_wsgi issue tracker is only marginally better than SO. On the mailing list it is easier to have a back and forth discussion.